# Android - Glide: How can I load images in order in a list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a RecyclerView with some tiles and an ImageView to display some image from the network. To load the image I'm using Glide and the the good ol' loading method:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(url)
        .into(myImageView)
```

Despite being correctly loaded, images load in a random order. I can't figure out how to 'specify' the order of loading.

- Is that even possible?
- Is there any tweak in the RecyclerView I could make?
- Does sb know about another library that supports this feature? Like Coil or Picasso.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In which Adapter's method you load images?

Comment: Curious - why does the order matter?

Comment: @MikhailGuliaev in the onBindViewHolder method!

Comment: @dominicoder someone from prod team asked me if that was possible. And since the RecyclerView dispatches Glide requests in order, but there are async jobs, I think there's no way of forcing or delaying some requests without 'dirty code' or handling the image requests manually. Right?

Comment: @Matilveiro Can't say for certain, but I'd assume not. The whole point of Glide is to be able to "fire and forget" loading of images. I know there are hooks for observing the images as they're loaded, so you could probably write some code to track each request and "catch" them as they come in, only allowing them to complete when its their "turn". But it does seem odd to care about the order they come in, especially in a RecyclerView where the user can just scroll around kicking things out of memory and triggering refetches. You can also try asking on the Glide project repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > Despite being correctly loaded, images load in random order.

From this statement my understanding is, all the images are correctly loading in respective ViewHolder but just the problem here is if there are 3 ViewHolders then you expect to load/display images from ViewHolder1, ViewHolder2, ViewHolder3 respectively but currently ViewHolder2 or ViewHolder3 might display image before ViewHolder1.

If my above understanding is correct then I want to add few points here:

1. The loading time of each image will be depending upon the various factor of the response image like its size, dimensions etc.
2. Whenever you will scroll in the RecyclerView the ViewHolders will again get bind which will lead to make a request again for the same URL. To improve this you have to use the Glide caching mechanism so that the unnecessary fetching will be avoided.
3. Regarding RecyclerView, you should try to implement it with DiffUtil, it is method by which the updates are more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! I explained my team that it wasn't possible without hard-wiring stuff or by handling downloads by hand. I didn't know about the DiffUtil interface, I'm gonna use it!